# If $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$ and $A,B$ are closed, then either $A$ or $B$ contains an interval.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1918449/39285) answer, the following fact is assumed:

> If $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$, then either $A$ or $B$ contains an interval.

**Why is that true?** I first thought that we can use measure theory: either $m(A)>0$ and $m(B)>0$ and hence one contain an open interval. But this is false since there are sets of positive measure not containing any interval (e.g. $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$). But $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed, so maybe *closed* sets with positive measure contain intervals?

Comment: This need not be true. There are 'fat' cantor sets which are closed sets of positive measure, but do not contain any intervals; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set.

Comment: @SamM how does this show it need not be true? What would the other set be?

Comment: Oh, I apologise, my comment is not very clear. I was answering the question: do there exist closed sets of positive measure which do not contain intervals. (The OP has since made the actual question more clear.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is not all of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is a nonempty open set, and so in particular it contains an open interval.  But $\mathbb{R}\setminus A\subseteq B$.

(Much less trivially, even if you have countably infinitely many closed sets whose union is $\mathbb{R}$, then by the Baire category theorem one of them must contain an interval.)